# How do I implement a memory block in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm developing an Javascript application for which I need to implement a fixed memory block of 64k. This block can be anything like object, array, buffer I don't know what.This should work as 64k physical memory chip. Which I can address and store data. Addresses will be 16 bits and data in each location is 8 bits. How can I implement it?  Can you recommend any npm packages?

Comment: For Node or for a browser?

Comment: For Browser....

Comment: That's exactly what `new Uint8Array(64*1024)` is made for.

Answer (score 4):

I think most browsers support [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) nowadays:

```
const buffer = new Uint8Array(65536);

let index = 123;
buffer[index] = 42;
console.log( buffer[index] );
```